# How I can read the encrypted file created with the gem called rails-env-credentials on Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, credentials

I am currently working on a project where I have to make id and passwords encrypted, so I decided to use the gem called `rails-env-credentials` https://github.com/sinsoku/rails-env-credentials

It seemed that creating some files for development is fine, but I can't read the file on console or on web.

I guess it is either because I didn't set something to be set which I don't come up with or I am trying to get the value in a wrong way.

with the command like this rails `env_credentials:edit -e development`, I made the config/credentials/development.yml.enc which has encrypted string of this

```
  aws:
    access_key_id: 123
    secret_access_key: 345
```

And in the config/credentials/development.key file, something like this is automatically created.

```
<rails secret key>
```

I expected to get the value of the file by calling this.

```
Rails.application.credentials.aws
```

But I get `nil`.

and when I do `Rails.application.credentials` on console, I get something like this.

```
#<ActiveSupport::EncryptedConfiguration:0x000055882a4965f8 
@key_path=#<Pathname:config/master-development.key>, 
@content_path=#Pathname:config/credentials-development.yml.enc>, 
@env_key="RAILS_MASTER_KEY_DEVELOPMENT", 
@raise_if_missing_key=false, @config={}, @options={}>
```

Since there is no error, I got stack in the same place for days.
If you have any ideas please let me know.
I would really really appreciate it.

EDIT****

in the encrypted file, there is something like this.
[image]
And I think I tried to get the value like the way to get value from hash but I can't get it correctly.

I tried something like

[image]

I am sorry but i have no ideas to fix this...

Do I have to do something with master.key?

Comment: Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, : access_key_id) try this

Comment: First, delete your master key from this post, that needs to stay secret and shouldn't be shared on something like this. That is used to decode the credentials, the second would be that you access it like a hash as others have suggested

Comment: @LHH thank you for your comment. I updated question and I think I have tried something right. but I can't get the value from the file..would you please check it ?

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery Thank you for your comment and advice. the key I wrote was a dummy so it doesn't matter but thank you for your kindness. I also updated my question, would you please give me any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the way for reading the credentials

```
Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id)
Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I just get `nil` on console.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy way to reading the credentials

```
Rails.application.credentials.aws[:access_key_id]
Rails.application.credentials.aws[:secret_access_key]
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I just get `nil` on console somehow

Answer (score 0):

If you are still stuck there then this is the way for reading the credentials

```
 Rails.application.credentials.config.dig(:aws, :access_key_id)
 Rails.application.credentials.config.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key)
```